# ASP.NET Core, Angular 7 publishing error "The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating..."

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core

the project was developed using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Angular 7. 
When you start from visual studio, everything works fine. 
After publishing, I get the error: "The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating the CLI was listening for requests." 
From the description of the error it is not clear what the problem is. 
Tell me, please, what's the problem?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "portal": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/portal",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/ui-theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "portal:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "portal:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "portal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "portal-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "portal:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "portal:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "portal"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please use 'ng serve' command on cmd.

Comment: ng serve: Compiled successfuly and the project is working.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue with .Net Core 3 and Angular 8.

Comment: @Neville Hi, yes I decided, but it was a long time ago and I don’t remember the decision. If I am not mistaken, the error was due to the placement of the angular application after publication.

Comment: Great. I just found my solution. The NPM command should not run on the server as that is for the development environment only. In my case I had the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable set in a web.config with value  Development. Changed it to Production and problem solved.

Comment: if you are just running your production build your own pc .Then set System environment `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable value  as  `production`. I face this kind of problem. I just set value as `Development'  in system environment. .I am using windows 10.please configure  startup.cs in core if your are uploading to the server

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the standard visual template of visual studio and creating an AspNet Web Application project and later creating the angular application.

You could follow below steps and recreate application and host in iis.

https://github.com/silvairsoares/Angular-with-Asp.Net-Core/wiki

Regards,
Jalpa.

Comment: If this is a small project or a new one, the option is suitable. And what about a big project like mine?

Comment: @jalpaPanchal, I have the same problem, and everything indicates that we've to separate the project from angular from .net https://stackoverflow.com/a/47911062/4668184 but as al.koval say my project is not a new one is a big one and the issue maybe generate a lot of new errors?